# How to make form field read only?

Tags: 8, forms

I want prevent any user from being able to change the value of a field, yet I want to display its value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done via hook_form_alter

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

   if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
      $form['field_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
   }

}
```

Add some css:

```
input:read-only {
  background-color: #ddd !important;
}
```

## Result:

[image]

Comment: This solution can be easily circumvented on client side. Use `'#disabled' => TRUE` as suggested in the other answer!

Answer (score 11):

And Just as a Reference, another solution is using the [#disabled](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled) attribute:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['field_name']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not exact. When a field is disabled and you programmatically set its value in the form, the value will be ignored, from the form validation handler and the form submission handler. When the field is readonly, the value will be handled.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to the question!