# How do I disable a checkbox on Facets Block?

Tags: 8, search

I would like to disable checkboxes of a Facets block.
The option will still be visible but the user will not be able to click it.

I am using Search API, Search API Solr, Facets.

I have created a widget extending the current checkbox widget and added the attribute readonly="readonly" to the item.

However, the checkbox is built using JS and it has got static text on it. It does not get any extra attribute.
So I am building my own JS library to do that.

All I want is to add readonly attribute to the checkbox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make you could try it via hook_form_alter as I did here [How to make field read only?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262646/how-to-make-field-read-only)

Comment: FYI there's an active core issue you might come up against: [Selected yet disabled individual options from checkboxes element don't persist through save](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2911473).